# Use custom content entity theme suggestions in own module?

Tags: theming, 9

I have a custom content entity called 'offer'.

I've added `template_preprocess_offer()` and `offer_theme()` to the  offer.module file.

```
function offer_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return [
    'offer' => [
      'render element' => 'elements',
    ],
  ];
}

function template_preprocess_offer(array &$variables) {
  foreach (Element::children($variables['elements']) as $key) {
    $variables['content'][$key] = $variables['elements'][$key];
  }
}
```

In *modules/custom/offer/templates/offer.twig.html*, I successfully render the entity.

Next, I've added theme suggestions because I've added a view mode 'full' via the UI.

```php
/**
 * Adds template possibility for view modes
 * Implements hook_provider_theme_suggestions_hook_alter
 */
function offer_theme_suggestions_offer_alter( array &$suggestions, array $vars, $hook ) {
  if ( $offer = $vars['elements']['#offer'] ) {
    if (isset($vars['elements']['#view_mode'])) {
      $suggestions[] = 'offer__' . $vars['elements']['#view_mode'];
    }
  }
}
```

After clearing caches:

```
<!-- THEME DEBUG --> <!-- THEME HOOK: 'offer' --> <!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS: * offer--full.html.twig x offer.html.twig --> <!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'modules/custom/offer/templates/offer.html.twig' -->
```

This **only** works if I place a offer--full.html.twig inside the **theme's** templates folder. It **doesn't work in the custom module template folder**. Inside *modules/custom/offer/templates*, the template file with the view mode won't get used. While the template suggestions suggests offer--full.html.twig, offer.html.twig is used instead.

Why does it happen? How can I solve it?

**Edit**: I'm on drupal 9. My custom entity has no bundles. I've made sure the id inside @ContentEntityType is "offer".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To make a theme suggestion work in the module folder you need an additional theme hook:

```
function offer_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return [
    'offer' => [
      'render element' => 'elements',
    ],
    'offer__full' => [
      'base hook' => 'offer',
    ],
  ];
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

> This only works if I place a offer--full.html.twig inside the theme's templates folder.
>
> It doesn't work on the custom module. Inside modules/custom/offer/templates.

My guess, it's because you're using `_alter`.

Since this is your module, you don't need to alter it. Instead use [`hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK/8.2.x).

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK().
 */
function offer_theme_suggestions_offer(array $variables) {
  $suggestions = [];
  $offer = $variables['elements']['#offer'];
  $sanitized_view_mode = strtr($variables['elements']['#view_mode'], '.', '_');

  $suggestions[] = 'offer__' . $sanitized_view_mode;

  return $suggestions;
}
```

Comment: Nice suggestion, but unfortunately this has no effect.