# Why is my template suggestion not called (the return)?

Tags: theming

I have seen many questions like this ones and I have tried all the solutions...

Here is my setup:

1-I have a custom entity with the id defined as follow:

```
 * @ContentEntityType(
 *   id = "bank_operation",
 *   label = @Translation("Bank Operation"),
```

2- My `hook_theme()`:

```
function bank_operation_theme() {
  return [
    'bank_operation' => [
      'render element' => 'elements',
     ],
  ];
}
```

3- My `hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK()`

```
function bank_operation_theme_suggestions_bank_operation(array $variables) {
  $suggestions = [];
  $sanitized_view_mode = strtr($variables['elements']['#view_mode'], '.', '_');
  $suggestions[] = 'bank_operation__' . $sanitized_view_mode;
  return $suggestions;
}
```

4- My Route to display the entity with a "receipt" view mode

```
entity.bank_operation.receipt:
  path: '/bank_operation/receipt/{bank_operation}'
  defaults:
    _entity_view: bank_operation.receipt
    _title: 'Receipt'
  requirements:
    _entity_access: 'bank_operation.view'
```

5-My twig files:

```
modules/custom/bank_operation/templates/bank-operation.html.twig
modules/custom/bank_operation/templates/bank-operation--receipt.html.twig
```

**Result: Everything works fine :**

-`receipt` view mode is used

-suggestions seems to be correctly added:

```
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'bank_operation' -->
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   x bank-operation.html.twig
   * bank-operation--receipt.html.twig
   x bank-operation.html.twig
-->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'modules/custom/bank_operation/templates/bank-operation.html.twig' -->
```

Except that `bank-operation--receipt.html.twig` is not called

I have tried all combinations of file name/suggestions/base hook name/... without any success

I have added all the possible twig file name in my `templates` folder (with or without dash)

I have the feeling that the problem is coming from the fact that the ID of my entity have an underscore in its name...

Comment: Additional template suggestions are picked up from the active theme, not from a module.

Comment: To pick it up from the module see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/298906/47547

Comment: You saved my day!!! many thanks!!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use custom content entity theme suggestions in own module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/298844/use-custom-content-entity-theme-suggestions-in-own-module)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else landing here, a lesson I learned the hard way, and not obvious from [the docs](https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/twig-in-drupal/working-with-twig-templates).

The beginning of the suggestion seemingly MUST match the 'THEME HOOK' plus two underscores. e.g. for the theme hook 'slick'

This should work

```php
function THEMENAME_theme_suggestions_slick_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables, $hook) {
$settings    = $element['#settings'];
if (!empty($settings['field_name'])) {
$suggestions[] = 'slick__' . strtr($settings['field_name'], '-', '_');
}
```

However

```php
$suggestions[] = 'slicktheme__' . strtr($settings['field_name'], '-', '_');
```

Will not work because "slicktheme" is not the theme hook. Additionally be sure that underscores, not hyphens, are added to `$suggestions` array using the `strtr` function or it will probably not work.

Comment: Note that you can do this, which is the way to ensure the lesson you learned isn't run into: `$suggestions[] = '$variables['#theme_hook_original'] . strtr($settings['field_name'], '-', '_');`