# Using template variations from the modules folder

Tags: theming

I have the usual theming solution for a custom entity:

```
function module_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return [
    'customentity' => [
      'render element' => 'elements',
      'template' => 'customentity',
    ],
  ];
}

function template_preprocess_customentity(array &$variables) {
  $variables['content'] = [];
  ...
}

function module_theme_suggestions_customentity_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  $sanitized_view_mode = strtr($variables['elements']['#view_mode'], '.', '_');
  $suggestions[] = 'customentity__' . $sanitized_view_mode;
}
```

The only problem is that when I want to use a twig specific to the view mode, `customentity--viewmode.html.twig`, it only works if the twig file is inside the theme. If it's in the module `templates` folder, it isn't picked up (carefully checked all cases with twig debugging).

So, in this regard, it's functioning. Still, I'd need the twig in the module itself because in this case, it's not a mere theming question, the view mode is both logically and programmatically a radically different way to present the contents. It's for internal use, not a contrib module, so normal user expectations don't apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the path to your theme hook like so:

```
'my_entity__mailteaser' => [
        'render element' => 'elements',
        'base hook' => 'my_entity',
        'template' => 'my-entity--mailteaser',
        'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'asdentbase') . '/templates',
      ],
```

Comment: Unfortunately, if I do this, it will no longer find my `theme.inc` file because it will be expected in the same folder. There are no separate path settings for both...

Comment: Anyway, I tried with putting the `theme.inc` there, too. No, it doesn't work. `path` changes where the system tries to find the attached `file` but doesn't change where it looks for the templates.

Comment: `base hook` is the correct solution. Drupal is then able to locate the template in the module's templates folder, even without pointing at it via `template` or `path`. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/298844/use-custom-content-entity-theme-suggestions-in-own-module

Comment: Not by itself but only if I add an extra theme item with the view mode glued to it, yes. you're right. Would you care to put it into a short answer for me to accept? :-)

Comment: @Gábor, see the linked topic. The code in question+answer is the complete solution.

Comment: Yes, I know, thanks, I utilized it. I just wanted to be able to accept it here.